# Getting layout.xml orientation/height/width properties from resource XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

First: What am I trying to do? A: I'm trying to do a basic layout reshuffle when the orientation changes **without** using any .java code of my own.

Here's my activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingTop="0dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:orientation="@string/wrapper_orientation"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@string/image_width"
        android:layout_height="@string/image_height"
        android:layout_weight="@string/image_weight"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="@string/content_width"
        android:layout_height="@string/content_height"
        android:layout_weight="@string/content_weight"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/customborder"
            />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:background="@drawable/customborder">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have a strings.xml file in both /values-land and /values-port, here's port for an example:

```
<resources>
    <string name="wrapper_orientation">vertical</string>
    <string name="image_width">fill_parent</string>
    <string name="image_height">0dp</string>
    <string name="image_weight">.45</string>
    <string name="content_width">fill_parent</string>
    <string name="content_height">0dp</string>
    <string name="content_weight">.55</string>
</resources>
```

This works fine in the emulator, but when I send this to my phone, the app force closes on inflation with the following errors:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "vertical"
```

I assume this is because however its retrieving the resource, the wrong type is being returned. But I'm not sure why or how to get around it. Two hours of googling hasn't been much help.

Just another note: If I hard-code the orientation to vertical, it then fails saying that my first ImageView has no layout_width, so I'm pretty sure I'm at least on the right track.

Am I being too much of a simpleton here in hoping to accomplish what I'm after this easily? Any help appreciated. I'm using the latest Android Studio, and my minSDK is 14. All my main .java file does at this point is the standard inflate, this proof of concept is all I've tried to do so far:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Thanks in advance!

Pic (linked, boo, no rep) of the emulator working fine:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFmhC.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In xml, the vertical and horizontal orientation designations are not strings, but integer constants pre defined. You are taking an incorrect approach to this problem. The better option is to use multiple layout files defined in resource directories with appropriate qualifiers. So you will have a `layout-port` and a `layout-land` folder in `res` with the layout xml file defined with the same name in each, with the the appropriate changes to the layout for each orientation. You can read more about resource qualifiers here:

[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was a noobish question but I wasn't aware you could use -port and -land folders for other subdirectories of /res.

Comment: If you don't want to create two layouts with only few `orientation` attributes changed, you can define those in styles (different for landscape/portrait). Pretty much any attribute can be defined this way and it is much easier to work with jus one layout file.

Comment: Thanks @Lamorak, I will have to look into that. I just got to the point where I realized why I wanted to do it more simply in the first place. :)